# Color of Dynamic table data based on condition using [ngClass]

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to make change table data value positive and negative based on condition. Is there any possibility to make it with [ngClass]. i can not get it this way. any idea?

```
<tr *ngFor="let gbh of gbhoil">

   <td  [ngClass] ="{'positive': gbh.Last > 0, 'negative': gbh.Last < 0}"> {{gbh.Last}} </td>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<td [ngClass]="{'negative' : myNumber < 0, 'positive' : myNumber > 0 }">{{myNumber}}</td>
```

I am using Above snippet which is same as your and its work for me.Check the type of "gbh.Last" that you use to bind. It should be Number type

Comment: I don't know where i went wrong.   this is type where i  want to bind:  export class GbhOilList { Last:number;}  then i did gbhoil:Array<GbhOilList>;

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You don't need the quotes:

```
[ngClass] ="{positive: gbh.Last > 0, negative: gbh.Last < 0}">
```